# Documentation/manual for stm32-wm8994 library?

Tags: stm32, audio-codec

I have a [STM32F746G-DISCOVERY kit](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html#overview) that has a [WM8994 (Audio Hub CODEC)](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8994_Rev4.6.pdf). I'm learning how to generate a sound from the STM32F746G and send it to the WM8994 via [Serial Audio Interface](https://www.st.com/resource/en/product_training/STM32F7_Peripheral_SAI.pdf) (SAI) to use in my [TouchGFX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/touchgfxdesigner.html) project. I found a driver for WM8994 ([stm32-wm8994](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-wm8994)) but there is no API documentation on how to initialize/use the driver. The Board Support Package (BSP) example for this board doesn't use this driver. Does anyone know if there is API documentation for this driver? or an example that is clear on how to initialize/use it? Thanks.

Comment: you need to read the README of that repo you found!

Comment: **Description** *This wm8994 MCU component repository is one element common to all STM32Cube MCU embedded software packages, providing the WM8994 BSP AUDIO component part.*

Comment: so, you look inside the wm8994.c and you find API documentation as doxygen comments, directly witth the function they describe. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: Neither the built-in help for each function nor the readme file you mentioned says how to use this library. By looking at the example for another board that uses this library in its BSP I was able to follow the code and see that I need to use WM8994_Init(...) first. But this function takes two pointers. I was able to figure out how to init one of them (WM8994_Init_t) but not the other (WM8994_Object_t). The more I look into the code the more stuff I see that I don't know ... something that should be in the documentation ... if such thing exist.

Comment: but you asked for API documentation, not usage manual! As usage manual replacement, the board examples are probably as good as it will get. But that initialization comes before you do anything else with the object: that's C knowledge, not really necessary to document that in a library. You'd always look first for the function that initializes the struct handler for your resource!

Comment: ok I change the title to make it more clear.  Such a nice piece of firmware and no documentation/manual... what a shame. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, yeah, a usage guide would be nice, but the function documentation is good, and you have examples. This seems to be partially a problem of C skills!

Comment: IMO, it's not difficult to figure out, but you may find the odd bug or two.